# How to load tensorflow models using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

import cv2
    import tensorflow as tf
    #i wan t
    # What model to download.
    MODEL_NAME = 'emotion'
    MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'
    DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'

```
# Path to frozen detection graph. This is the actual model that is used for the object detection.
# PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'
PATH_TO_CKPT = 'age/frozen_inference_graph.pb'


# List of the strings that is used to add correct label for each box.
PATH_TO_LABELS1 = os.path.join('data', 'gender.pbtxt')
PATH_TO_LABELS2 = os.path.join('data', 'age.pbtxt')

NUM_CLASSES1 = 2
NUM_CLASSES2 = 7


# ## Download Model

# if not os.path.exists(MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'):
if not os.path.exists('screwdriver_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb'):
    print('Downloading the model')
    opener = urllib.request.URLopener()
    opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE)
    for file in tar_file.getmembers():
        file_name = os.path.basename(file.name)
        if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name:
            tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd())
    print('Download complete')
```

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /io/opencv/modules/dnn/src/caffe/caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "graph.pbtxt" in function 'ReadProtoFromTextFile'